# Is there a name for an instance when someone misleads themself on the meaning of a word?

Tags: terminology

Suppose someone has encountered the word "transfixed" on several occasions, never looked up the word in a dictionary, and concluded from the encounters that the word means "engrossed".

They have unwittingly misled themself as to the meaning of the word, and not been misled by anyone else. So, now, they say things such as "the students were transfixed in the notes".

Comment: Acquisition :) But no, there probably is a term for this specific type of error, which obviously drives much semantic change. I'm curious.

Comment: It’s a kind of imperfect learning, but I don’t know of a more specific term.

Answer (score -2):

It's a form of self-deception. The only word I can think of is misdefining: to incorrectly identify or set forth the meaning of (something, such as a word) : to define wrongly.

It's such a unused word it gets tagged as misspelled.